# After editing a commit by rebase how to apply it to the origin branch?

Tags: git

I have a two people group, I work in master while the other work on dev branch.

One day, after merge dev branch I found my partner delete a file by mistake and push this "commit with del" into the remote so I re-add the file in master branch using `rebase -i dev` and change the "commit with del" to "commit with no del".

Now in my master branch, I only have the "commit with no del". Everything works.

Then I want to fix dev branch for my partner.

But when I checkout to dev branch and merge from master, the deleted file is still not there and the messages is shown as

> Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.

I checked my git log now, found both commits are in dev branch log, one is "commit with del" the other one is "commit with no del" so the file is deleted not kept.

What's the right way to resolve this problem?

the final master branch log, clean and beautiful:

```
commit e1e49880fe159888e68db4c84ab82c2c5da567ca (HEAD -> master)
Author: me
Date:   Fri Sep 27 11:00:52 2019 +0800

    commit1

A       FPMS2FUNC.cs

commit 6e47f19a595192a4c001738d76436b8d9475dab6
Author: partner
Date:   Fri Sep 27 10:56:15 2019 +0800

    commit with no del

M       CAMS1_GEN.rst

commit 09d382f442f24783451d15f489a1df6a42aaf05f
Author: me
Date:   Fri Sep 27 10:55:35 2019 +0800

    init

A       CAMS1_GEN.rst
A       CAMS2_GEN.rst
```

the final dev branch log:

```
commit cf1acb5a649cd9015c30eed6a94bec684c56fa0e (HEAD -> dev)
Merge: f98661f e1e4988
Author: me
Date:   Fri Sep 27 11:04:36 2019 +0800

    Merge branch 'master' into dev

commit e1e49880fe159888e68db4c84ab82c2c5da567ca (master)
Author: me
Date:   Fri Sep 27 11:00:52 2019 +0800

    commit1

A       FPMS2FUNC.cs

commit 6e47f19a595192a4c001738d76436b8d9475dab6
Author: partner
Date:   Fri Sep 27 10:56:15 2019 +0800

    commit with no del

M       CAMS1_GEN.rst

commit f98661fe330a1ff20f57641581c59093c36c68ca
Author: partner
Date:   Fri Sep 27 10:56:15 2019 +0800

    commit with del

M       CAMS1_GEN.rst
D       CAMS2_GEN.rst

commit 09d382f442f24783451d15f489a1df6a42aaf05f
Author: me
Date:   Fri Sep 27 10:55:35 2019 +0800

    init

A       CAMS1_GEN.rst
A       CAMS2_GEN.rst
```

the final reflog:

```
cf1acb5 (HEAD -> dev) HEAD@{0}: merge master: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
f98661f HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to dev
e1e4988 (master) HEAD@{2}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/master
e1e4988 (master) HEAD@{3}: rebase -i (pick): commit1
6e47f19 HEAD@{4}: commit (amend): commit with no del
f98661f HEAD@{5}: rebase -i: fast-forward
09d382f HEAD@{6}: rebase -i (start): checkout 09d382f442f24783451d15f489a1df6a42aaf05f
01395be HEAD@{7}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/master
01395be HEAD@{8}: rebase: commit1
f98661f HEAD@{9}: rebase: checkout dev
bbd86ef HEAD@{10}: commit: commit1
09d382f HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from dev to master
f98661f HEAD@{12}: commit: commit with del
09d382f HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from master to dev
09d382f HEAD@{14}: commit (initial): init
```

Comment: You said that you made a mistake at dev branch and you fixed it with rebase. Then you said that you checkout to dev and merge from master. Are you sure that is what you meant? Didn't you mean merge in the opposite direction?

Comment: Also, please add output from git reflog.

Comment: @BugHunter, Sorry for lack of git reflog, I have tried too much times and lost the specific part. I'll improve the question.

Comment: @BugHunter, I simulate the actions in a new git repo and post logs in the question

Comment: Have your friend made any new commits on develop after you rebased master?

Comment: @BugHunter, of course yes, but the commit is still on remote, not in my local branch